# ContextSwitchDeadlock error - VS 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I am creating an extension for similar functionality that we had as an addin.

When I debug the extension, and the experimental instance of VS is opened, I get this:

> ContextSwitchDeadlock occurred
>   Message: Managed Debugging Assistant 'ContextSwitchDeadlock' has detected a problem in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe'.
>   Additional information: The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0x1272878 to COM context 0x12727c0 for 60 seconds. 
>   The thread that owns the destination context/apartment is most likely either doing a non pumping wait or processing a very long running operation without pumping Windows messages. 
>   This situation generally has a negative performance impact and may even lead to the application becoming non responsive or memory usage accumulating continually over time. 
>   To avoid this problem, all single threaded apartment (STA) threads should use pumping wait primitives (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and routinely pump messages during long running operations.

I read this post:
[Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578357/visual-studio-contextswitchdeadlock?rq=1)

and unchecked the ContextSwitchDeadlock from the Exception Settings, but I didn't feel comfortable with that.

Then I found this post (particularly Scott Munro's answer):
[Similar problem 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797677/contextswitchdeadlock-was-detected-error-in-c-sharp?rq=1)

and used the steps to get to the Thread window, but on examining the Main thread I only see this:

```
Main Thread     Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.ResourceLoader.FindResource.AnonymousMethod__0
[External Code]
```

So that doesn't help me much.

How do I solve the ContextSwitchDeadlock? Apart from simply unchecking it in the MDA. I have also tried to install the published vsix (not uploaded to the gallery) on my computer, but it made VS hang on the splashscreen. I assume it is related to this whole issue.

This is what the main thread shows (row column transformation):

> Main Thread
>   Main Thread Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.ResourceLoader.OpenAssemblyResourceManifest4
>   Normal

And this is what the Worker thread that complains shows:

> Worker Thread 
>   clr.dll!Thread::intermediateThreadProc()
>   ntdll.dll!_NtWaitForSingleObject@12   Normal

I can't see anything in the callstack, or find what my code is busy with.